# Regex.IsMatch for specific special characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to Regex, I know this is a simple question but couldn't find a solution

I have a set of special characters (&, !, $, |) and a string. I just need to check whether the string contains any of these special characters.

I tried with this but couldn't make it out.

```
string _validateText = ".*&!$|.*";
string _myString = Value;
if(Regex.IsMatch(_myString, _validateText))
{ 
   //My Code  
}
```

I ignore all the other special characters. Tried with multiple String.Contains but need to do in Regex. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Use a character class with anchors`

```
^.*[&!$|].*$
```

Comment: Or even easier simply use "[&!$|]" as the regular expression.